# Glide 4.0.0 fails to load GIFs from URL with a strange size change and DecodePath issues

Tags: android, android-glide

My code looked like this:

```
GlideApp.with(c)
    .asGif()
    .load(pathToPicture)
    .into(memePicView);
```

This netted me the following stacktrace

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://img.memecdn.com/japan-strikes-again_webm_3923465.gif with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ContentLengthInputStream->GifDrawable->GifDrawable}, REMOTE
            Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ContentLengthInputStream->GifDrawable->GifDrawable}
```

I could access said gif from the browser, and the size of that gif is not `[-2147483648x-2147483648]`. Was there some setting that I missed, and do I have to implement an `okhttp` or `Volley` integrated App Glide Module?

And I do have the Internet permission in my Manifest. In case anyone asks.

I've tried downloading the GIF into the app's internal data directory and loading it from there with Glide. Still no dice with the exact same error, except replace ContentLengthInputStream with FileInputStream.

Comment: does it works with plain images??

Comment: Hello mate ,Did you find any solutions regarding this issue . Actually I'm having this too

Answer (score 3):

https://img.memecdn.com/japan-strikes-again_webm_3923465.gif is not a GIF. It looks like a webm, which is a movie format. Not sure why, but lots of websites are using the .gif extension for non-gif files, including animated webp and movie files.

Comment: So should I just use `asVideo()` instead, and what about playback control in that case?

Comment: Glide doesn't really deal with video playback. It can display video thumbnails well for local content, but it never plays videos directly. Take a look at VideoView or ExoPlayer if you want to handle video playback: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the gif with [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) library:

```
Ion.with(imageView)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.load("http://example.com/image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **asGif()** and It will work!

```
GlideApp.with(c)
.load(pathToPicture)
.into(memePicView);
```

Refer: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

Comment: It may work, but it doesn't play. That's the problem. I used asGif() because I thought it had to be a GifDrawable to be playable.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this kind of problem with Gif-images loading try to use

`options.set(GifOptions.DISABLE_ANIMATION, false)`

For example (Kotlin):

```
GlideApp.with(c)
    .asGif()
    .load(pathToPicture)
    .into(memePicView)
```

change to:

```
GlideApp.with(c)
    .asGif().apply {
        options.set(GifOptions.DISABLE_ANIMATION, false)
    }
    .load(pathToPicture)
    .into(memePicView)
```